# WSO2 Carbon - custom mediators in common policies

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

where i can find in Carbon option to upload my own mediators inside common policies, so its possible to choose from these menu bar and its not necessary to upload file into custom policies in publisher ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you share which API Manager version you are using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to upload your custom policies as common policies in WSO2 API Manager

- Construct your mediation policy and save it with proper naming convention and extension
- Navigate to the Carbon Management console of the API Manager server (`https://localhost:9443/carbon`) and log in with Admin credentials
- Expand `Resources` accordion and click on `Browse`
- Go to `/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences` path and choose either `in`, or `out`, or `fault` Resource Collection based on where your mediation policy wants to be listed
- Click on `Add Resource` and upload the content

  - Method: `Upload from content`
  - File: Upload the mediation policy file
- Click on `Add`

Once the above steps are executed successfully, you can log in to the Publisher portal and select the custom mediation policy from the Common Policies section.

Comment: This answer is just a copy of documentation how to manually create and upload a new mediation policy. It doesn't answer the question of how to create a Carbon application with policy definition.